# Any idea for making image hotspot (WP)

Tags: wordpress

For Wordpress, how can I make it like https://store.google.com/us/category/connected_home

Hotspot info, Top-tab for changing the spot. Can be made with slide revolution?

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the page. They've positioned the elements with percentage based `left` and `top` values.

If I was to build something like this, I'd use javascript to hide and show the various labels when I click the menu tabs. And I'd add CSS animations so they transition in like in your example.